# output shape of BucketIterator

Tags: python, torchtext

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIgrP.png)
I'm trying to create a batch through BucketIterator from train_data and test_data created by TabularDataset.splits().

I wanted a batch of the shape (128,1), but it returns a batch of the shape (1,128). I tried transposing and got the desired result. How should I modify the code?